# x-editable angular: how to set a field value programmatically

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I would need to be to Set the value of a (hidden) X-editable field with my angular controller.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide more information so that others have something more concrete to answer. For example, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi,I've tried to add a, input field in the x-editable form

Comment: My problem is that I need to store some additional infos in the X Edit form. I haven't form the way to do it (all changes are not reflected back to scope and save end). 

Typically this information are stored in hidden fields of the forms but I haven't found a way to set this values programmatically. 

Please help